# Meaning of "Is" & "In"

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

What is the meaning of `is` and `in` in VBScript? Because they appear in blue when I write them in UFT.

Can I use them to **check whether a value exists** in matrix **without looping**? Because that's actually what I'm looking for. I mean something like this:

```
If "Ahmed" is in Matrix() Then
    msgbox "He's in"
End If
```

Comment: `is` is used to compare two object references, `in` does not exist in VBScript it is a JScript operator for checking for the existence of a property in an object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But 1- Could you give an example for `is`. 2- If `in` is not used in VBScript, then why does it appear in blue as if it has some builtin function?

Comment: It's most commonly used to check whether an object reference has been released from memory. `If MyObject Is Nothing Then`. As for `in` being highlighted is due to it's use in the `For Each ... In ....` statement when enumerating a collection of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt). The [`Is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ake1y5wx) operator is used to check if two object references (object variables) point to the same object:

```vb
Set sh1 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set sh2 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set sh3 = sh1
WScript.Echo "" & (sh1 Is sh2)        'Output: False
WScript.Echo "" & (sh1 Is sh3)        'Output: True
```

The keyword `In` kind of exists in VBScript, but only as part of a [`For Each`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tywtbxd0) loop:

```vb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'"In" used in For Each loop.
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\some\folder").Files
  WScript.Echo f.Name
Next
```

You could use a `For Each` loop for checking if an array (one array dimension to be precise) contains a specific value:

```vb
For Each element In arr
  If element = refElement Then
    ...
  End If
Next
```

I'm not aware of a way to check if a VBScript array contains a specific element without a loop, though (unless you count joining the elements to a string and then testing for an element with `InStr`, which doesn't work for all data types). You could do that with a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```vb
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "a", True
d.Add "b", True
WScript.Echo "" & d.Exists("a")       'Output: True
WScript.Echo "" & d.Exists("c")       'Output: False
```

or an [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```vb
Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
al.Add "a", True
al.Add "b", True
WScript.Echo "" & al.Contains("a")    'Output: True
WScript.Echo "" & al.Contains("c")    'Output: False
```

However, using different data structures would most likely require changes to the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks :) 
One other thing, is there a way to check whether a specific value exists in an array without loops? (that was another part of my question actually)

Comment: No, you must inspect each Array element :D